# how do i connect to mysql database in Linux server through windows machine

Tags: mysql, windows, linux

I have a MYSQL in windows that needs to connect with MYSQL in Linux server.but I want to know is there any way to connect MYSQL in Linux server without having MYSQL in windows.

Comment: You can connect to the MySQL server if the two machines are on the same network.

Answer (score 3):

```
Follow the following instructions:
1. Open Terminal and type in : sudo apt-get install putty
2. Click Y on subsequent messages that appear and let the installation complete.
To use Putty, go to Menu > Internet > Putty SSH client

To connect to a remote server that supports ssh login , enter the host name or the IP address of the remote host, in case you need to frequently need to login to this server , save the session by naming it something nice.

If the connection is initiated for the first time or if the server hardware configuration has changed, you may see the message. This is to ensure that you are logging in only to the trusted server that you know and not something else.Accept that.

Finally, enter user name and password to login to the server remotely, if all goes well you will see the terminal on the remote end.

connect to mysql :
type mysql -u username -p password
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use putty software. Here is the [link to download.](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can use putty for connecting mysql.
Connection string will like this

mysql -uDBUSER -pDBPASSWORD DBNAME -hHOST-IP

Or you can also use navicat or sql yog software to connect mysql on linux system on remote.